# php and mongodb - get the results as a public array collection

Tags: php, mongodb

Using the php mongodb driver "command" function, instead of getting a collection as an array, I'm getting a collection as an object with each item being a private ArrayObject.

```
$stores = $mongodb->command([
    'geoNear' => 'stores',
    'near' => [
        'type' => 'Point',
        'coordinates' => [
            $lng,
            $lat
        ],
    ],
    'spherical' => true,
    'maxDistance' => 30000,
]);
```

This :

```
$results = $stores->toArray()[0]->results;
foreach($results as $result) {
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Returns that :

```
object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)[17]
  private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
    array (size=2)
      'dis' => float 13002.060182992
      'obj' => 
        object(MongoDB\Model\BSONDocument)[16]
          private 'storage' (ArrayObject) => 
            array (size=4)
              ...
```

I'd like to return a collection as a public array, so that I can then `array_map` on the array, and use the 'dis' and 'obj' property.

Comment: You're using the wrong driver. This output comes from the core driver intended for developers of" abstracted drivers only". There is a [PHPLIB](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/) driver which has all the standard API methods. Including a `toArray()` on the cursor and conversion to stand plain object types. The PHP split of these parts of the driver is confusing and people have been complaining and loading the wrong one for years. You also don't need to run `command()` as the regular query methods are there.

Comment: Other note [`geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/command/geoNear/) is deprecated officially from MongoDB 4.0 and will be removed in future releases. You should be using [`$geoNear`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/) if you want a "distance" in all new code. But get the correct driver which actually has an `aggregate()` method as well first.

Comment: Wrong driver ?  I'm using driver dll version 1.4.3. I don't see a driver download in your link  .   I'm using this : https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb   . I think I use the right driver

Comment: Using `getArrayCopy`,  I can convert the parent object to an *array* of objects.  Then I can `array_map` : `$results = array_map($myFunc, $results->getArrayCopy());`

Comment: Thats the "core driver". The problem is is a prerequesite install to the PHP Lib. I linked to the full Manual. Click on ["installation"](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/tutorial/install-php-library/) for instructions. The instructions are for composer as preference, but you can install with other tools if you like. The ["pretty picture"](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.overview.php) also demonstrates where the different things fit together. So Wrong driver and you need to install the correct one for your application usage.

Comment: That is exactly what I've done.  I'm using `composer require mongodb/mongodb` and the dll downloaded from https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb

Comment: Why are you running `command()` then? No need to do that. Run `aggregate()` with `$geoNear` and use `toArray()` on the resulting `Cursor`. Then it's just plain objects in an array. To me though it looks like you "installed" but all your code is referencing `MongoDB\Driver\Manager` when it should be `MongoDB\Client`

Comment: I don't have an aggregate function :  `$stores = $mongodb->aggregate([  ....`   : `Call to undefined method MongoDB\Database::aggregate()`

Comment: Exactly. Because you are using the wrong driver. Please take some time and actually read the documentation at the link provided. I really don't know how to be more clear without either seeing your entire code and correcting it ( really too broad ) or writing a minimal usage example of what you should be doing instead. Take a look at [`MongoDB\Collection`](https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/current/reference/class/MongoDBCollection/) which is where the method resides, and was part of the documentation link you were originally given.

Comment: @NeilLunn, your link does not provide the driver that you talk about.  If the right driver is not there : https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb , then please tell me exactly where it is.